# How to retain current tab in a code slider after a postback in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Im creating  an asp.net booking page that has a coda slider effect,the page is also a content page of a master page, i have this JavaScript that allows the slider effect

```
<script>
            var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
            showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

            function showTab(n) {
                // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                x[n].style.display = "block";
                // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
                if (n == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("Submit").style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
                }
                if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
                    document.getElementById("Submit").style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
                }
                // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
                fixStepIndicator(n)
            }

            function nextPrev(n) {
                
                // This function will figure out which tab to display
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
                if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return true;
                // Hide the current tab:
                x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
                // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
                currentTab = currentTab + n;
                // if you have reached the end of the form... :
                if (currentTab >= x.length) {
                    //...the form gets submitted:
                    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
                    return false;
                }
                // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
                showTab(currentTab);
            }

            function validateForm() {
                // This function deals with validation of the form fields
                var x, y, i, valid = true;
                x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
                y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
                // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
                for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    // If a field is empty...
                    if (y[i].value == "") {
                        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                        y[i].className += " invalid";
                        // and set the current valid status to false:
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
                if (valid) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
                }
                return valid; // return the valid status
            }

            function fixStepIndicator(n) {
                // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
                var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
                x[n].className += " active";
            }              
        </script>
```

The problem is that i have this button for a file Upload control that does a postback to display a label to show if the file is uploaded

```
            <input type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload File" onserverclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

but the  page current tab returns to the first tab after post back, how can i prevent this from happening? this is the code that runs after i have clicked the "Upload File" button

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (payment.HasFile)
        {
            string FileExtention = Path.GetExtension(payment.FileName);
            if (FileExtention.ToLower() != ".pdf" && FileExtention.ToLower() != ".docx")
            {
                message2.Visible = true;
                message3.Visible = false;
                message.Visible = false;
                message1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                int FileSize = payment.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (FileSize > 2097152)
                {
                    message3.Visible = true;
                    message2.Visible = false;
                    message.Visible = false;
                    message1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    payment.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ApplicantUploads/" + payment.FileName));
                    message.Visible = true;
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            message1.Visible = true;
            message3.Visible = false;
            message.Visible = false;
            message2.Visible = false;
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general technique, define a hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" value="" />
```

Create a javascript function to save the current tab position:

```
function SaveTabPosition(position) {
     document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField.ClientID%>').value = position;
 }
```

When the POST will take place, it will send also the "currentTab" value stored in HiddenField back to the server. In the response now you will have to use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "setTabPosition", "var currentTab="+HiddenField.Value, true);
```

Now you should have the tab position back on the client side in "currentTab" variable. As a small mention, the "currentTab" should be accessible.

Comment: Thank you for being such a great help, your solution worked, it does retain the current tab however, now it doesn't run my whole code, it only reads the message in the last else statement which can only show if the File Upload button doesnt have a file, so even if the FileUpload button has a file it will still show the last message which is "Please select a file". PS i've added the ScriptManager at the bottom of all the code in the method.